# iOS Facebook latest SDK cannot login through native App but browser

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

i just download and update existing Facebook SDKs. After update, i found my app cannot login through facebook native login screen. It show web site login. Anyone can help on this issue? i am using original facebook login button. code below is the way i use it

```
loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error{
       if (error) {
          alertMessage = @"Facebook Process Error";
       }
       else if (result.isCancelled) {
           alertMessage = @"Cancelled Login";
       }
       else
       {
           [self getFbUserData];
       }
}

-(void)getFbUserData{
     [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

     if (!error) {
         fbID = result[@"id"];
         [self FacebookRegToServer:result[@"id"] facebookName:result[@"name"]];
         self.statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@"You're logged in as",result[@"name"]];


     }
 }];
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code where we can look at...

Comment: hi, i have add some coding.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: By Design.

The reason for this is that Facebook doesn't want to pop up an alert asking you to open Facebook every time you login with apps that integrate the SDK, therefore they will always pop up a webview. More on this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)